# Why does my weight paint not reflect the arrangement of my sprinkles?

Tags: weight-painting

Why do the sprinkles appear below the desired surface as well?
I don't quite understand why it skipped my selected surface.

I'm sure there is some easy explanation.
[image: In weight paint view with sprinkles visible from below]

[image: The actual area i wanted to have full of sprinkles from above]

[image: In regards to the comment stating i linked the wrong geometry nodes tree, this is a new screenshot]

[Blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/axh85sc9qz8y2bm/Cookie_3.1.blend?dl=0)

Comment: maybe you need to invert the normals, or it may be the position of the particle origin

Comment: Unfortunately you're showing a different geometry node tree than the one that is selected on the object. Please click on the pin icon in the node editor and post the screenshots again :)

Comment: pls provide blend file so it is easier/possible to check out the problem

Comment: I added a link with the file. It's really small.